# Understanding generic union types in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm having some trouble understanding what exactly the `Html msg` type is, or how it gets used. I found this line of code in VirtualDom.elm, which `Html msg` seems to be an alias of:

```
type Node msg = Node
```

This looks like a generic union type with one type parameter, `msg`, and one trivial case that holds no additional information. I'm wondering:

1. How does the `div` function construct one of these objects?
2. How does an object like this get used?
3. How could an object like this get used?
4. Is there any value for a user to define a type like this, or is `Html msg` just a magical type to support the Elm compiler/runtime?

Comment: This pattern is fairly common for defining Opaque types, whose structure is actually manipulated by Native JS code. You can see this here: https://github.com/elm-lang/virtual-dom/blob/1.1.0/src/Native/VirtualDom.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Html msg` is a [Type Alias](http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/type_aliases.html) for `Node msg`, which is a [Generic Union Type](http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html#generic-data-structures)

#### Union Type `Node msg`

It only makes sense to reason about `Node msg` type signature in a context of Elm Architecture, where all input for your application, except flags for `Http.App.programWithFlags`, is happening through messages.

`msg` type variable in `Node msg` is only hinting you towards the idea, that all messages from your DOM sub-tree should belong to a single union type.

```
node
    :  String
    -> List (Attribute msg)
    -> List (Html msg)  -- List of children nodes with a msg
    -> Html msg         -- Produced DOM node
```

#### How `div` function uses generic Union Types

Thanks to `msg` type variable, Elm compiler knows, when your DOM tree is correct in the context of Elm Architecture.

In JavaScript world `Node` value of `Node msg` Union Type is representing the object with the following structure:

```
{  
   "type":"node",
   "tag":"div",
   "facts":{},            // Attributes and DOM events
   "children":[],         // Children, have the same structure
   "descendantsCount": 0  // Used for Virtual DOM diffing
}
```

#### How you can use generic Union Types

Most of the complex core data structures are implemented using generic Union Types, check [Maybe](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.3/Maybe) or [Dict](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.3/Dict) to get inspired.

#### `Html msg` and user-defined generic Union Types

`Html msg` in particular is somewhat magical, but you can implement some interesting structures, like linked lists or other tree-like structures.

```
type List a =
  Empty | Node a (List a)
```

Comment: Union Types are now called "Custom Types" in 0.19 https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/custom_types.html